# External Authentication Services with an Client page

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-web-api2

I am using facebook/twitter logged in user to authenticate my web api. i followed [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services)

Okay that was most likely what I what. But my view page will be differently hosted. That is user will be logging in with a different page and they will send an ajax request get values from api controller.

I would authorize the web api only to user who is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

If by "differently hosted" you mean on separate domains, then you won't be able to share a cookie between the two.  If you mean that the client is a iOS app or Windows Phone app running on a device, the general pattern is to use a "Browser Control" and build a little UI as part of your API site.  You can show your users this UI in the browser control and then scrape the token out.  If you use Azure ACS, this is much easier with the "javascriptnotify" protocol that enables the token to be pushed out of the browser control.

The best article I've seen on this is http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/04/04/authenticating-users-from-passive-ips-in-rich-client-apps-via-acs-2